# What should the Tor SE chat be called?

Tags: discussion, chat

Should we create a chat room on the SE chat network, and if so, what should it be called? `Tor Talk` like the IRC channel?

Comment: How about, `The Exit Node`? Has a similar flavor to [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access).

Comment: That's a good one; I like it.

Comment: I also like that suggestion. If you post it as an answer then it will become easy for us to check the favourite by vote count (unlike comments which are mostly linear)

Comment: Actually, we might not be able to create a room until we're in public beta (my mistake), but either way, it's worth discussing (not that it matters that much).

Comment: It would be very useful. I'm one of those people who doesn't use IRC. I could write better questions with prior feedback. I can go always back and edit, of course, but then maybe I cause upset.

Answer (score 13):

How about `The Exit Node`? Has a similar flavor to [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access).

Answer (score 2):

I think we'd be better off not having an SE chat room, and instead directing users to `#tor` on OFTC. I don't see what an SE chat room provides that's unique and distinct from `#tor`, but I'm happy to be convinced otherwise.

Comment: Lots of people won't want to learn to use IRC; also we probably don't want people discussing SE related things on the #tor channel. #tor has a specific topic, the SE channel will be about Tor, but also about Tor.SE and the sorts of things that go on the Meta site.

Comment: So the SE channel will be meta?

Comment: It would be anything related to Tor, or the SE site. Yah, lots of questions and things will be meta (but not exclusively); people often post links to questions that haven't been answered (but need to be), or ask questions that are a tiny bit offtopic, or wouldn't work as a full question for some other reason, etc. To get a feel for why it's different, hang out in some of the other popular SE rooms for a bit.

Comment: The room is a good place for _site specific_ discussions, so I don't want to just redirect folks to IRC. However, there's no problem if people want to just hang out in IRC, and use SE chat when the utility of it makes sense. Still needs a good name, though :)

Comment: Chat advantages: OneBoxing (try to post an image/video/question/github/etc. link in chat...), having chat mods who are trusted by the site, because they are elected moderators (who are the IRC Ops? did they sign a moderator agreement? were they elected?). having users linked between chat and site, and probably many more.

Comment: I'm still not really convinced. It seems that this is more likely to force the core Tor team and support folks to add yet another interface to keep track of, rather than providing a specific, unique, tangible function. For reference the Tor IRC channels on OFTC are operated by the core Tor team. I suspect that many of them (me included) would not commit to another form, potentially either making a ghost town or splitting knowledge.

Answer (score -3):

IMO people should learn to use and jump on IRC instead. I don't think if it's a good idea to have a chat room here. As most likely we probably won't be able to get enough Tor people on it like we do on #tor. 
Things can go very wrong as soon as clueless users will start to educate other clueless users about Tor... and there's no one to warn them about potential risks, etc.

Comment: Chat can be useful for coordinating site curating / janitorial tasks, or for moving extended comment conversations to somewhere more productive where they're still archived. We automatically expand question / user links in chat, and it's tied in with our notification system. It's fine if folks want to use IRC, but chat has some utility use that could come in handy even for those that don't use it frequently.

Comment: IRC and SE chat serve very different purposes.